# Command to block an IP range using IPSEC

Tags: windows, firewall, ipsec

I think there is command with netsh .... But not sure about the exact command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in Windows 2003 or newer OS's to add a policy, a filter list, and an entry to that filter list:

```
netsh ipsec static add policy name="Prevent TELNET Servers" description="Prevents running TELNET servers"
netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist="My filter list" srcaddr=any srcport=0 dstaddr=me dstport=23 protocol=tcp mirrored=yes
```

You can use "dstmask" and "srcmask" to specify ranges of IP addresses. Bear in mind that you'll have to actually assign that policy if you want it to *do* anything.

Some background on using NETSH and IPSEC is available at Microsoft at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739550(WS.10).aspx

On XP machines you'll use the IPSECCMD.EXE utility, available from the Windows 2000 resource kit.